Dynamically fill the spreadsheet underlying the charts of a MS Word document from ABAP
I have a MS Word template containing in some part of it an empty Chart (e.g. line chart). My requirement is to find a way to fill the data of the spreadsheet underlying the chart (see picture below) from ABAP and fill the the data dynamically.
Is it possible to do this from ABAP? Any suggestion or guidance to the right path would be highly appreciated.

I used this tool zcl_docx and was able to generate normal tables in MS Word dynamically with data coming from Internal Table in ABAP with ease but it doesn't offer the access to the underlying table of the chart.

There's no ABAP API for .DOCX. Search any API in other programming languages. Otherwise, the concept of zcl_docx is to rework the XML files inside the .DOCX file. Just look at the differences in two .DOCX files between two sets of chart values. NB: I use ABAP z_zip_diff_demo and VS Code to quickly find the differences.

I get your point about zcl_docx, we actually use the library now to generate Word reports from ABAP with much ease than before. But this new requirement is something complicated I thought maybe somebody faced this before and was able to find a solution to fill data in the spreadsheet of the charts from ABAP. Thank you anyways

everything is possible with abap2xlsx, check demo 39 from their demo gallery
